# How to access a member variable of a class even after class destruction?

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding the usage of a member variable of a class. 
Suppose, I have a class `ABC` and I have a member variable `Buffer` declared as public within the class, how can I use the variable `buffer` even after the class has been destroyed?

Can I declare the variable `buffer` as static? Will that allow me to access the variable even after the class has been destroyed?

Comment: Why not just assign the member variable somewhere else that's still in scope, before class destruction?

Comment: You don't destroy a class, you destroy *instances* of a class. A static class member is part of the class, not its instances. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I want the variable to be accessible even after the class has been destroyed. I do not want to copy the variable to another variable that is still in the scope. I have a real time application which necessitates this

Comment: If you declare it as static then it will be accessible outside the life of any single instance of the class but it will also be shared by all instances of that class. If that is not acceptable then you will have to follow @RobertHarvey's advice and save that buffer somewhere before destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some examples will help.

```
class ABC
{
public:
    std::queue<int> buffer;
};
// All of the above is a class

void foo()
{
    {
        ABC c; // c is now an instance of class ABC.  c is an 
        //object created from class ABC
        c.buffer.push_back(0); // you can change public members of c
    }
    // c is now destroyed.  It does not exist.  There is nothing to access
    // ABC still exists.  The class has not been destroyed
}
```

But, here's a possibility:

```
void foo()
{
    std::queue<int> localBuffer;
    {
        ABC c; // c is now an instance of class ABC.  c is an 
        //object created from class ABC
        c.buffer.push_back(0); // you can change public members of c
        localBuffer = c.buffer;
    }
    // c is now destroyed.  It does not exist.  There is nothing to access
    // ABC still exists.  The class has not been destroyed
    // localBuffer still exists, and contains all the information of c.buffer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the member after destruction of the object only when you declare it as static, because then it is independent of the lifetime of any object of the class.

However, I am not sure that this fits your use case. your variable is named `buffer`, which implies some kind of producer pattern. It would be quite a bad design to write to a static buffer from another method in your class. Can you explain what you want to do in more detail?

Assuming you have a producer in mind, one solution might be to pass a string by reference when constructing your instance of the class which then buffers to this external string. Then the caller will still have the result after destruction of the instance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Producer
{
public:    
    Producer(string &buffer): m_buffer(buffer) { }
    void produce() { m_buffer.assign("XXX"); };
protected:
    string &m_buffer;
};

int main()
{
    string s;
    Producer p(s);
    p.produce();
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: So, this variable stores the value of the width of an image. When I copy this variable into a global variable outside the scope of the class and then call the global variable, I get an error. I understand what your code means now. Thanks!